# Reusing DAL in ASP.Net Web Forms in Sencha

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sencha-touch-2, webforms, sencha-architect

I have a N-tier web application built in ASP.Net Web Forms.  The application registers users for a youth sports program - and it works great!  The client has asked me to build a mobile version of registration.  I'm going to need to build a new front end and that's ok.  Modifying the current Web Forms for mobile is not an option.  I really like Sencha Architect and know the IDE well enough to consider using Sencha as a front-end.  Plus I love the benefits of Sencha offers with cross-device (Android/iDevice) web applications.

My question is how best to architect the application.  I don't want to rewrite the DAL (or any stored procs) so I'm considering a few options:

**Backend**
1) Leverage the EF and trying to work with my existing SPs (although this seems cumbersome to say the least)
2) Use the new ASP.Net Web API to craft service endpoints that call SPs

**Front-End**
1) Use Sencha Architect
2) Use ASP.Net Web Forms (altough I'm concerned about rewriting what Sencha has already done well)
3) Use ASP.Net MVC (concerned about rewriting what Sencha has already done well)

Ideally, I would find some sort of way to reuse the DAL I have.  I don't want to manage two Data Access Layers in this application.

Thanks!

Comment: I should clarify and say that I don't mind modifing the DAL but I don't want to rewrite the SPs, there seems no reason to do that.